# SQL Server : how to join record not in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to show the appraisal submission status of the staff.

It will add one record in the `Appraisal_Record` table if the file had been submitted.

How can I write the SQL that shows all appraisal periods for all staff even though they had not submitted the appraisal (no records). Add a column "Status" to indicate the status, "Submitted" and "Not_Submitted" <- if no record in [Appraisal_Record] table

i want to use a case in sql statement to add a column... CASE WHEN xxx then "Submitted" ELSE "Not_Submitted" as Status

Thanks

The following is the example

Table: `StaffDB`

```
+---+-----+
|SID|Name |
+---+-----+
|1  |Peter|
+---+-----+
|2  |John |
+---+-----+
|3  |Amy  |
+---+-----+
```

Table: `Appraisal Period`

```
+--------+-----------------+
|PeriodID|PeriodDescription|
+--------+-----------------+
|1       |2012_Start_Term  |
+--------+-----------------+
|2       |2012_Mid_Term    |
+--------+-----------------+
|3       |2012_End_Term    |
+--------+-----------------+
```

Table: `Appraisal_Record`

```
+--+---+--------+
|ID|SID|PeriodID|
+--+---+--------+
|1 |1  |1       |
+--+---+--------+
|2 |1  |2       |
+--+---+--------+
|3 |2  |3       |
+--+---+--------+
```

**Result**:

```
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|SID|Name |PeriodID|PeriodDescription|Status       |
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|1  |Peter|1       |2012_Start_Term  |Submitted    |
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|1  |Peter|2       |2012_Mid_Term    |Submitted    |
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|1  |Peter|3       |2012_End_Term    |Not_Submitted|
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|2  |John |1       |2012_Start_Term  |Not_Submitted|
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|2  |John |2       |2012_Mid_Term    |Not_Submitted|
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|2  |John |3       |2012_End_Term    |Submitted    |
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|3  |Amy  |1       |2012_Start_Term  |Not_Submitted|
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|3  |Amy  |2       |2012_Mid_Term    |Not_Submitted|
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
|3  |Amy  |3       |2012_End_Term    |Not_Submitted|
+---+-----+--------+-----------------+-------------+
```

Thanks Kishore and Damien.

The solution is:

```
select a.sid,a.name,b.periodid,b.perioddescription,
CASE WHEN c.ID IS NOT NULL then 'Submitted' ELSE 'Not_Submitted' as Status
from 
StaffDB a 
cross join 
[Appraisal Period] b
left join 
Appraisal_Record c on a.sid = c.sid and b.periodid =  c.periodid
```

Comment: You need a cross join between StaffDB and Appraisal Period.

Comment: @joe ann from which table the status comes from

Comment: hi kishore, i want to use a case in sql statement to add a column... CASE WHEN xxx then "Submitted" ELSE "Not_Submitted" as Status

Comment: with the below given query you can achive this rite.?

Comment: Given @Kishore's answer, your `CASE` becomes `CASE WHEN c.ID IS NOT NULL then 'Submitted' ELSE 'Not_Submitted' as Status`

Comment: Thanks Kishore and Damien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this you are looking for (assuming status column in your appraisal_record table )

```
select a.sid,a.name,b.periodid,b.perioddescription,c.status
from 
StaffDB a 
cross join 
[Appraisal Period] b
left join 
Appraisal_Record c on a.sid = c.sid and b.periodid =  c.periodid
```

Comment: `status` should be computed based on whether or not the `LEFT JOIN` succeeded.

Comment: ohhh if it is null we should compute as Not_submited...?

Comment: Yes. That's how I interpret the question. I was going to answer but it was substantially similar to yours except for computing the `status` column.

Comment: it works. thanks a lot. i am trying to add the "status" column